# Why the Green's function is zero on the Dirichlet boundary surface?

Tags: mathematics, boundary-conditions, differential-equations, greens-functions

Given a differential equation

$$
Lu(x) = f(x),
$$

where $L$ is the differential operator, and $f$ is a given function of $x$, the general solution of $u(x)$ is

$$
u(x) = \int G(x, s) f(s)\, ds
$$

$G(x, s)$ is the Green's function of $L$ and satisfies

$$
LG = \delta(x - s)
$$

If we have Dirichlet boundary conditions like

$$
u(a) = \alpha,
$$

$\alpha$ is a given number, this differential problem is called the Dirichlet problem.

My question is why $G(a, s) = 0$ with given a boundary condition $u(a) = \alpha$?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Check again, may be field is curly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that your problem is linear non-homogeneous. You have two sources of inhomogeneity: the boundary condition ($\alpha$) and the sources ($f(x)$). Instead of solving the entire problem in one go, you want to treat the inhomogeneities one at a time and use superposition to reconstruct the original solution.

This is simply linear algebra. Take for example a $d$ dimensional vector space $E$ and $e^1,…,e^d$ basis vectors of the dual space. Say you want to solve the system of equations for $x\in E$:
$$
\langle e^1,x\rangle =a^1\\
…\\
\langle e^d,x\rangle =a^d
$$
and $a^1,…,a^d$ known constants. As you can see, you could try to solve the equation directly or construct the dual basis $e_1,…,e_d$ defined by:
$$
\langle e^i,e_j\rangle=\delta^i_j
$$
i.e. you normalize only one inhomogeneity and make the other constraints homogeneous. Your solution can this be directly solved to:
$$
x=\sum_i a^ie_i
$$

Formally, you can apply the same reasoning to your problem. The solution to your problem is therefore:
$$
u(x)=v(x)+\int G(x,s)f(s)ds \tag{1}
$$
with:
$$
LG(x,s) = \delta(x-s), \quad G(a,s)=0 \\
Lv(x) = 0, \quad v(a)=\alpha
$$
I think that part of your confusion comes from the fact that you forgot the first term.

Hope this helps.

**Examples**

Applying the method when $E$ is finite dimensional shows that it’s a pedantic way of introducing the inverse matrix. Take $E=\mathbb R^2$, and:
$$
e^1 = (L^1_1, L^1_2) \\ 
e^2 = (L^2_1, L^2_2) \\
$$
then let:
$$
e_1=\begin{pmatrix}
G_1^1 \\
G_1^2
\end{pmatrix} \quad e_2=\begin{pmatrix}
G_2^1 \\
G_2^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The duality condition is equivalent to the definition of the inverse matrix:
$$
LG=I_2
$$
In particular if you want to solve the system:
$$
Lx=a
$$
then you’ll use:
$$
x=Ga
$$

A more advanced example would be $L=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ giving the bulk equation:
$$
-\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}=f \tag{2}
$$
and Dirichlet boundary conditions at $x=0,1$:
$$
u(0)=\alpha_0 \\
u(1)=\alpha_1 \tag{3}
$$
You then have:
$$
G(x,s)= \min[(1-s)x,s(1-x)]\\
v(x) = \alpha_1x+\alpha_0(1-x)
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not good at linear algebra. Can you give me an example above this line? 

$$x=\sum_i a^ie_i
$$

Comment: Does $v(x)$ satisfy $Lv(x) = 0$?

Comment: Yes it’s in the last equation. I’ll give some examples. Btw it’s best to be confident in linear algebra as most of physics is about extrapolating its results.

Comment: I am still confused by the last example. In your last example $Lv(x)$ is $-\alpha_1 + \alpha_0$, and $LG(x, s)$ is not $\delta(x -s)$. Do I misunderstand anything?

Comment: My bad, I forgot the square…

Comment: If I change $v(x)$ to $v'(x) = \alpha_1 x + \alpha_0 (1 - x) + 1$ and pull $u(0) = \alpha_0$ into $u(x)=v'(x)+\int G(x,s)f(s)ds$. I get

$$
u(0)=v'(0)+\int G(0,s)f(s)ds = \alpha_0 + 1 + \int G(0,s)f(s)ds = \alpha_0
$$
This means $\int G(0,s)f(s)ds = -1$, and $G(0,s)$ should not be zero. Why I cannot change $v(x)$ to $v'(x)$?

Comment: I’d write $\tilde v$ rather than $v$ to avoid confusions with the derivative. The issue is that $\tilde v$ does not satisfy the Dirichlet boundary conditions since:$$\tilde v(0)=\alpha_0+1\\ \tilde v(1)=\alpha_1+1$$

Comment: Why $\tilde{v}$ need to satisfy the Dirichlet boundary conditions? The boundary conditions are set on $u$, aren't they?

Comment: Remember, $u$ is the solution to the set of equations $(2),(3)$, that you want to construct. If you still want to write $u=\tilde v+Gf$ the simplest method is that $\tilde v$ must satisfy the same boundary conditions as $u$. You could not do that, but then you’ll change need to redefine $G$ to adapt its boundary condition. Things get messy and arbitrary, which is why the first method is usually preferred.

Comment: Does it mean G may not be zero at the boundary surface if I want? Do we let it be zero because being zero makes the calculation easier?

Comment: Yes exactly. Adding a function in the kernel of $L$ still makes it a GF.